# Android: What to do about E/art: ClassLinker::FindClass not found issues in log

Tags: android, gradle

For a while now I'm being tormented with error logs in my logcat of which I have no idea what to do about. They look like:

```
erexample E/art: ClassLinker::FindClass not found:Lokio/ForwardingTimeout;
```

E/art: ClassLinker::FindClass not found:Lokhttp3/internal/http/Http1xStream$ChunkedSink;
E/art: ClassLinker::FindClass not found:Lokhttp3/internal/http/Http1xStream$1;

E/art: ClassLinker::FindClass not found:Lokhttp3/internal/http/Http1xStream$ChunkedSource;

E/art: ClassLinker::FindClpass not found:Lokhttp3/internal/http/Http1xStream$AbstractSource;
 E/art: ClassLinker::FindClass not found:Lokhttp3/internal/http/Http1xStream$FixedLengthSink;
E/art: ClassLinker::FindClass not found:Lokhttp3/internal/http/Http1xStream$FixedLengthSource;

E/art: ClassLinker::FindClass not found:Lokhttp3/internal/http/Http1xStream$UnknownLengthSource;
E/art: ClassLinker::FindClass not found:Lokhttp3/internal/http/StatusLine;
E/art: ClassLinker::FindClass not found:Lokhttp3/internal/http/RequestLine;
E/art: ClassLinker::FindClass not found:Lokio/SegmentPool;

E/art: ClassLinker::FindClass not found:Lokio/Segment;

etc. etc.

Calling FindClass not found on tens and tens of classes for classes belonging to different libraries (Glide, OkHttp, SupportLib, etc.)

I have no idea what's going wrong here and what to do about it.

Is there anyone to enlighten me?

Comment: Same problem for me.

Comment: @user1434702  Use the answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40021462/classnotfoundexeption. My problem is solved by updating `android studio` to `2.2.2` and `gradle calss path` to `2.1.0` (I already had `gradle-wrapper-properties` set to `2.14.1.all` and maybe this was the origin of the problem for me)